# Angular 4 http throws error on PUT response without body

Tags: angular, http

I am using Angular http module v4.4.6. When the Angular application (client) is sending a PUT request (using `HttpClient`) to the server, and the server responses a status 200 (OK) without any data in body, angular http module throws an `HttpErrorResponse`.

Is this a proper feature or a bug?
How to handle PUT responses without any data in body?

---

In Detail:

In recent versions I have used normal `Http` module and it's  method put(). There I need to call `res.json()` to get the JSON data in body. The put() method returns `Observable<Response>`.

Now I use the newer `HttpClient` and it's put() method. This method returns `Observable<Object>`. It seems that the `json()` method is called internally and leads to the error I see.

- Angular client creates PUT request with HttpHeader `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`. This results in a HTTP PUT request header `Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*`).
- The server answers with status 200 (OK) and without any data in the body.
- The Angular client receives the answer and throws the error.

`HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, ...
         error:
           error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at ..
         text: ""
         headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: ...
         message: "Http failure during parsing for ...
         name: "HttpErrorResponse"
         ok: false
         status: 200
         statusText: "OK"
         url: ...`

Comment: Did you try https://angular.io/guide/http http
  .get('/textfile.txt', {responseType: 'text'})
  // The Observable returned by get() is of type Observable<string>
  // because a text response was specified. There's no need to pass
  // a <string> type parameter to get().
  .subscribe(data => console.log(data));

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#put

Comment: At the moment I use the following statement: `const response =  await this.http.put(this._serverUrl + url, data, options).toPromise()`. If http is from `Http`, it returns a `Response`, if it is from `HttpClient` it returns the body as object (expecting a JSON inside the body).

Comment: @yonexbat, I have now changed request header to `'Accept:text/plain` (before it was `Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*`). The error is also thrown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@yonexbat, Thanks you are right.

If using ....

```
const response = this.http.put(url, data, { responseType: 'text'}).toPromise();
```

... the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The corret code in Angular 7/8 is

```
const options = {responseType: 'text' as 'json'};
const response = this.http.put(url, data, options).toPromise();
```

Don't ask why this stupid approach is valid :-/ See [link](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18586#issuecomment-327417876)